# Vanishing of $H^0( D, \hat{\Omega}^1_D)$ on simply connected surface $D$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The situation is similar to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69643/question-about-arguments-using-du-bois-complex)

Let $D$ be a reduced projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ whose associated analytic space $D_{an}$ is simply connected as a topological space i.e. $\pi_1 (D_{an}) = 1$. 
Let $\Omega^1_D$ be its K\"{a}hler differential sheaf and $\hat{\Omega}_D^1$ be its double dual.

**Question** Is $H^0(D, \hat{\Omega}_D^1) = 0$? Is there some counterexample?

I'm considering how to deduce the above statement from the fact $\mathbb{H}^0 (D, \underline{\Omega}_D^1) = 0$ where $\underline{\Omega}_D^1$ is the graded piece of the Du Bois complex $\underline{\Omega}_D^{\bullet}$. But I don't know the way up to now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but it's not true. Let $D$ be a cone over an elliptic curve with vertex $p$.
It is simply connected, but  $H^0(D,(\Omega^1_D)^{**})= H^0(D-p, \Omega_{D-p}^1)\not=0$.

**Added** to address your question below: $H^0(D,\Omega_D^1)=0$
for any degree $d$ surface in $P=\mathbb{P}^3$, and so in particular for the example above. You can see this using the exact sequences
$$0\to \mathcal{O}_D(-d)\to \Omega_P^1|_D\to \Omega_D^1\to 0$$
$$0\to \Omega_P^1(-d)\to \Omega_P^1\to \Omega_P^1|_D\to 0$$
and Bott's vanishing.

---

This goes to show that differentials can behave strangely on singular spaces.
The Du Bois complex, exotic as it is, is thing that works best from certain points
of view.

Comment: Thank you for the nice counterexample. Does it satisfy $H^0(D, \Omega^1_D) \neq 0$?